# What code will close a the command line window when 'Cls' does not?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that launches standalone Hangouts, but the `cmd` console window does not close, not even when 'CLS' or 'ECHO OFF' is the last line. What code would close the command line window ?

I have the answer - I just need to precede the existing code with : Start ""

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the complete batch file. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Neither `CLS` nor `echo off` will close a window. `CLS` is for clearing the window and `echo off` is for suppressing the batch commands itself. Probably you are searching for `EXIT`

Comment: I got the idea of 'Cls' from many batch examples in the notes I accumulated over the years.

Comment: which batch examples said that `cls` closes the console?

Comment: The simplest of a number of old examples is : to open a dial up connection box :
Echo Off
START C:\Desktop\Optus.lnk
Cls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `Start` command.

Try the following example to see what I mean:

```bat
@Calc.exe
```

Now try this one:

```bat
@Start Calc.exe
```

All you need to do is replace `Calc.exe` with the name of your actual executable.

BTW, if your program or its path contains spaces, you should use this format, *where `""` is a blank title, (can optionally be filled).*

```bat
Start "" "C:\Path To\My Program.exe"
```

I hope this helped

Comment: I have the solution I need; but I am puzzled by your '@'

Comment: @JosephPhilippa `@` before a command would typically jact as `echo off` for a single command. Thus not displaying the command itself, it will only display the value. for instance in a batch file, `echo Hello` will display on cmdline `echo Hello` as well as thereafter the value `Hello`. Where @echo  Hello will only display the value `Hello` on the cmdline.

Answer (score 0):

```
exit
```

You might even choose to put a number behind it, which generally means :

```
exit 0 // successful exit
exit 1 // erroneous exit (something went wrong)
```